# Golang - Why do the behaviors of `http.Get` differ between Windows and Linux?

Tags: go

I am trying to call `http.Get` over `http://example.com/path/to/index`, and I have resolved `example.com` to one of my inner IP address.

My Go code:

```
resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/path/to/index")
```

On Windows, this blocks forever until connection timeouts.
However, on Linux, it works totally fine.

What is wielder is that I have tried both `curl http://example.com/path/to/index` and translated the Go code to Nodejs one, they all work fine on Windows, which make me sure that domain resolving is ok on my Windows.

So I wonder why the behaviors of `http.Get` differ on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Name resolution or firewalls are the likely causes of the problem.  Print the output of [net.LookupHost("example.com")](https://godoc.org/net#LookupHost) to determine if name resolution is working as intended.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I have already tried that. The output is correct. Besides, curl and nodejs should fail too if name resolution or firewalls are making trouble.

Comment: There is no Windows specific code in the http client code itself.  When the application is blocked forever (or not forever because it times out?), dump the gorotuine stacks to determine where the application is blocked.  One way to dump the stack is to send the process a SIGQUIT.

Comment: @EricZheng: Your Go code works on Windows. The usual problem in these cases is an anti-malware/virus program. Try disabling it.